# Empty Bucket in HIVE

Tags: hive

There is 65 GB of data and I have created 40 buckets in HIVE but after data loading I found that 5 buckets remain empty. What could be the possibilities for these 5 empty buckets ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate how your table is created and how data is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your data is inserted, my guess is that you are using a Hive version below 2.x but `hive.enforce.bucketing` is not set to `true`. Or you didn't explicitly offer a `cluster by` clause when data is inserted.